# Is there a way to calculate the cost (time and memory) of excel calculations?

Tags: excel

For example, if I need to decide between making one column an array formula or making two additional sumif columns then adding them together, how can I make a good decision?

Comment: you can use vba to stop calculation, launch a timer, call Calculation, stop timer (and display it) and reset calculation to original value

Answer (score 0):

You can use the RangeCalc addin downloadable from http://www.decisionmodels.com/downloads.htm 
This gives you accurate timing of the calculation of the selected cells, so you can compare calculating the array formula with 2 SUMIF columns (the SUMIF columns will probably be faster)